# Substituir CTRL + F padrão dos navegadores por um evento jQuery

Tags: jquery, navegador-de-internet

Onde eu tenho tabelas em meu sistema, em quase todas utilizado o plugin dataTables pra personalizar, mas meu plugin ta um pouco modificado.

Na modificação em questão, o campo de busca dentro da tabela vem oculto, e eu ativo ele com um botão 'ativar busca'.

O que eu quero fazer ativar essa busca com o teclado, preferencialmente CTRL + F, fazer isso é simples:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey) {
     $("#dataTable_filter").find('.form-control').show().focus();
  }
});
```

Mas nisso, ele ativa a busca padrão dos navegadores, e move o foco para essa outra busca, a dúvida é:

> Existe como desativar essa busca padrão dos browsers e usar somente o
>   meu disparador? Ou é preciso fazer de outro modo pra conseguir esse
>   resultado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste adicionar e.preventDefault();

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey) {
     $("#dataTable_filter").find('.form-control').show().focus();
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Se não funcionar tente utilizar desta forma:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) { 
        $("#dataTable_filter").find('.form-control').show().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: Acrescento duas coisas: 1) não é 100% seguro de conseguir o mesmo efeito em todos os browser; 2) é extremamente errado, do ponto de vista da usabilidade, fazer isso, posto que você modifica um comportamento que seu usuário já está acostumado, e isso vai trazer uma péssima percepção por parte dele.

Comment: Sua resposta está certa. Estou apenas avisando ao @anthraxisbr que evite substituir funções nativas do browser por soluções próprias. Isso causa desconforto e, em termos de UX, é péssimo.

Comment: Marquei os seus comentários como importante para ele ler.

Comment: Eu havia esquecido da prevenção default, funcionou certinho, a respeito de poratabilidade de browser não faz difença, é um sistema intranet e todo mundo que utiliza possue todos os programas na mesma versão em seus Pcs.